# How to insert my validated info? (SQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I've got a little question, so I've wrote a piece of HTML and PHP which would register an account. Now I've done the validation, but how do I insert my data into my database, when all the validation is good: so there are no errors.

I know the SQL syntax, don't worry about that. I just only want to insert when all the validation was good and there were no validation errors.

CODE:

```
<?php
        $usernameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $password_valErr = "";
        $username = $email = $password = $password_val = "";

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
                $usernameErr = "Name is required";
            } else {
                $username = validate_input($_POST['username']);
                if($username <= 6) {
                    $usernameErr = "Username must be longer as 6 characters.";
                }
                if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username)) {
                    $usernameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed.";
                }       
            }

            if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } else {
                $email = validate_input($_POST['email']);
                if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $emailErr = "Invalid email format.";
                }           
            }

            if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $passwordErr = "Password is required";
            } else {
                $password = validate_input($_POST['password']);
                if($password <= 8)  {
                    $passwordErr = "Password must be longer as 8 characters.";
                }
                if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
                    $passwordErr = "Password must contain atleast 1 number.";
                }
            }

            if(empty($_POST['password_val'])) {
                $password_valErr = "Password_val is required";
            } else {
                $password_val = validate_input($_POST['password_val']);
                if($password_val != $password) {
                    $password_valErr = "Password_val must be equal to password.";
                }       
            }
        }
        ?>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Username</label><?=' <b>' . $usernameErr . '</b>';?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$username;?>" placeholder="Enter your desired username..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>E-mail</label><?=' <b>' . $emailErr . '</b>';?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$email;?>" placeholder="Enter your email address..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Password<?=' <b>' . $passwordErr . '</b>';?></label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your desired password..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Repeat Password<?=' <b>' . $password_valErr . '</b>';?></label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password_val" placeholder="Repeat your chosen password.." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is your database structure?

Comment: You need to create a connection to your database and then execute your sql

Comment: If you show can tell me your table structure I will write a PDO code for you? For E.g. tablename(username. email-id, password, salt)

Comment: I just need to know how to only run the query when all input is validated true.

Comment: set a boolean to true when your validation is all ok, then put the sql execute in an if statement 

if ($isValidated) {
 //your sql inserting code
}

Comment: Hide your database structure man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $usernameErr="Name is required";
} else {
    $username=validate_input($_POST['username']);
    if($username<=6) {
        $usernameErr="Username must be longer as 6 characters.";
    }
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
        $usernameErr="Only letters and white space allowed.";
    }
}
if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $emailErr="Email is required";
} else {
    $email=validate_input($_POST['email']);
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr="Invalid email format.";
    }
}
if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $passwordErr="Password is required";
} else {
    $password=validate_input($_POST['password']);
    if($password<=8) {
        $passwordErr="Password must be longer as 8 characters.";
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
        $passwordErr="Password must contain atleast 1 number.";
    }
}
if(empty($_POST['password_val'])) {
    $password_valErr="Password_val is required";
} else {
    $password_val=validate_input($_POST['password_val']);
    if($password_val!=$password) {
        $password_valErr="Password_val must be equal to password.";
    }
}
if(!isset($usernameErr,$usernameErr,$emailErr,$passwordErr,$password_valErr)) {
    //Insert QUERY
}
```

Comment: So i'd do:

`if($usernameErr == ' ' && $emailErr == ' ' && $passwordErr == ' ' && $password_valErr == ' ') {
//query
}` That should be it?

Comment: Thank you very much. Well Aviz, what would you do? Just interested.

Comment: I am just saying ... Boolean seems more safer than empty strings. Your solution will work fine though.

Comment: @Aviz how would you use this boolean?

Comment: @Peurr - set  $isValid = False; at the top of the file, and then set a $isValid=True; after each of your validate lines, then at the bottom do an if ($isValid) { //sql insert code }

Comment: Haha it will work .. I normally just use HTML_Quickform2 .. so I feel that way

Comment: @yonessafari it is more code, honestly, I'd have a validate method to cover this stuff and return either a true or false boolean, but this code structure wouldn't support that. I'd do the variable because I'd rather make one check than 5

Comment: Thank you guys, for all of your help.. I guess it's both good, both works though. :)

Comment: Try HTML_Quickform2 if your are into OOP  ..it builds the forms, you can set your own rules for every input and validate everything before submission.

Comment: @Aviz I might try that, I'm not very deep into OOP yet though.

Comment: @Peurr - Aviz makes a good point, why aren't you validating prior to submission?

Comment: @salty I don't know. I haven't been programming for long, so I'm still new to somethings.

Comment: @Peurr - I dig it, we were all new once. You should look into doing form validation via javascript or jquery prior to even letting the form get submitted, that way you can make sure the variables are how you want them prior to passing them. At that point you just need to check that they're set. Here's a good place to start http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp